# the evolution of the human brain size

Tags: human-biology, evolution, brain

I was thinking, as I know, sometimes the process of producing `DNA` did not work well(**correct me if I'm wrong**), so it gives us some changes in the *object* we gonna have(for example: increasing or decreasing a part, enabling  or disabling  a part), *could human brain grow more that it is now*?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: This question basically asks if there is a possibility that human brain can evolve to be bigger or more complex. This is an open ended question and cannot be addressed based on facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you mean by "producing DNA" Neanderthals had larger brains than us. Basically, this is possible and generally, brain size correlates with body size. What you may ask here is: Can our brain size to body size ratio increase? Probably yes... I can't think of a reason, why not?

But please please be aware of that intelligence, does not have to correlate with brain size. e.g. elephants and humans. There may be some limits of the smallest possible brain size for certain mental tasks and skills. But wiring and plasticity is probably more important than the bulk size.

Comment: Referenced material would be useful. Right now it's just your opinion and I see no attempt to answer the question beyond a purely opinion based "yes"